# Google Glass multiple level menu

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I was wondering if it is possible to do a multi-level menu with Google Glass that responds to voice, something like:

```
Connect  
Disconnect  
Command  
->Forward  
-->Slow  
-->Fast  
->Backward  
-->Slow  
-->Fast  
Sensors
```

An example to call it, "ok glass -> Command -> Forward -> Slow"...

IIf not with submenus, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if I didn't understand the question correctly:

Yes, you should be able to do this through some sort of submenus...the way that Glass has "play a game" open up a new set of options with game names seems like it would work.

The other option would be to have your command launch an activity that just has a ListView and you can put your commands in the listview and then do voice recognition on those to use them as commands.

Comment: You understand the concept, but with normal menus I'v seen that a submenu in a submenu doesn't work. The activity idea is a work-around but there must be an easier way that I'm not aware of.